# Django Template's Date Filter Causes Form Values To Disappear

Tags: python, django, modelform

I'm facing a weird dilemma. Django `date:"Y/m/d"` filter prevents the form values to show up if the form is not validated. Here's my ModelForm:

```
DATE_INPUT_FORMATS = ['%Y/%m/%d', '%Y-%m-%d']

class PromotionModelForm(ModelForm):
    last_promotion_date = 
forms.DateField(input_formats=DATE_INPUT_FORMATS)

    class Meta:
        model = Professor
        fields = ['last_promotion_date']
```

Here's my view:

```
def first-view(request):
    professor = get_object_or_404(Professor, 
user__username=request.user)
    form = SomeForm(request.POST or None, instance=professor)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        context = {"form": form}
        return redirect('/first-view')
    else:
        return render(request, 'core/first-view.html', 
context={'form':form})
```

and here's the template:

```
<form class="inner_box" method="POST" action="{% url 'core:first_view' %}" name="">
            {% csrf_token %}
          <table>
            <tr class="table_header">
              <th colspan="8" class="right">last_promotion_date</th>
              <td><input type="text" name="last_promotion_date" onfocus="displayDatePicker(this.id);" class="date_picker" value="{{ form.last_promotion_date.value|date:"Y/m/d"}}"</td>
            </tr>
</form>
```

And here's the problem 
if the form is not valid, and if I keep the `date:"Y/m/d"` filter, the form values which have that filter do not show up in the rendered response. 
However, if I remove the `date:"Y/m/d"` filter from the template variables, the form is rendered *including* the invalid input.

The problem with the `date:"Y/m/d"` filter happens only when the form is not validated. The very same date values that get rendered in a 'GET' request, disappear in the response of a 'POST" request if the form is not validated.

It's quite puzzling. What am I missing here? Why the invalid form's values do not appear in the presence of `date:"Y/m/d"` filter?

Answer (score 0):

If field won't validate, it's value probably won't be proper `date` object or anything that can be parsed to valid date. That's why using `|date` on value won't produce any result.

Comment: I think so. What's the solution? I think I have to render the cleaned data in the template?